# Azure Policy not working (check for lowercase APIM Url)

Tags: azure, azure-policy, apim

I have a simple Azure Policy that should check if all API-management URL's are lowercase (Display Name and API Url Suffix), but violations still pass the check, so obviously the policy is incorrect.

I am new to writing my own Azure Policies... Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

```
"policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/path",
                "notEquals": "[toLower(string(field('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/path')))]"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/displayName",
                "notEquals": "[toLower(string(field('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/displayName')))]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Policy not working (check for lowercase APIM Url)

Here is the updated `Azure Policy` checks whether the API management **display name** and **URL** are lowercase. If either the display name or the path is not lowercase, it is considered **non-compliant** otherwise, it is **compliant**.

The display name is located within the **properties** of API management.

[image]

**Azure Policy:**

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "not": {
                "field": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/path",
                "equals": "[toLower(string(field('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/path')))]"
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "field": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/properties/displayName",
                "equals": "[toLower(string(field('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/properties/displayName')))]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

**Compliance result**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work, as you can see for the Echo API that has a displayName of "Echo API" and is Compliant in your screenshot.

Comment: The display name 'echo-api' is shown in lowercase in my screenshot, which is compliant. If any display name is in uppercase, it will be marked as non-compliant

Comment: That's not correct. The screenshot shows the name, not the Display Name. The Display Name of the echo api is "Echo API" (at least the default Echo API you get from Microsoft), so it should show up under the name "echo-api" as non-compliant. In my subscription everything is also compliant, the problem is that things that are NOT compliant still show as compliant.

Comment: Hi @Edwin, I'll check and update the status.

Comment: Hi @Edwin, I have updated the answer according to your requirements. Please let me know if this has resolved your query.

Comment: Hi @Venkat V, I implemented your policy and let you know the result. I have to wait for the next policy eval...

Comment: Btw, I found this PS script to find all names: $temp = Get-AzPolicyAlias -Namespace 'Microsoft.ApiManagement'
$temp.aliases | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'displayName' } | Select-Object -Property Name

Comment: Unfortunately, everything is now not compliant, so maybe the /properties/ part is incorrect or some other strange thing is happening. Thanks for your patience though!

Comment: Have you verified if any display name in API management is displayed in lowercase, Even if the display name is shown in lowercase, it's still marked as non-compliant?The policy will fetch if the display name is uppercase, it will be marked as non-compliant, otherwise complain,  For testing purposes, remove the API path field from the policy and keep only the display name, then test the result.

Comment: Yes, even if the displayname is in lowercase it is still marked as non-compliant. So it really puzzles me. I asked our service provider to create a ticket for Microsoft to have a look at my and your policies. I'll keep you informed through this SO question. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Sure, let me know, if any help is required.